# How to get my Stripe Payment system to work?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe into my app, but when I use the following code, the payment page does not stop loading. What am I doing wrong?

`ViewController()` is where the button to take the order is:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Stripe

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var totalAmount = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    @IBAction func goToPaymentButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("checkoutClicked")
        let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController()
        addCardViewController.delegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(addCardViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
extension OrderDetialsViewController: STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate {

  func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    print("0")

  }

    private func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController,
                             didCreateToken token: STPToken,
                             completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
        print("addcardviewcontroller")
    totalAmount = 0
    if localData.shoppingCart.itemSizeArray.count > 0{
        for i in 0...localData.shoppingCart.itemSizeArray.count-1{
            if localData.shoppingCart.itemSizeArray[i] == "hd"{
                totalAmount = totalAmount+2000
            }
            else if localData.shoppingCart.itemSizeArray[i] == "d"{
                totalAmount = totalAmount+4000
            }
            else if localData.shoppingCart.itemSizeArray[i] == "free" {
                totalAmount = totalAmount + 0
            }
            else if localData.shoppingCart.itemSizeArray[i] == "home"{
                totalAmount = totalAmount + 500
            }
        }
    }
    StripeClient.shared.completeCharge(with: token, amount: totalAmount) { result in
        print("stripeclientsharedcompletecharge")
      switch result {
      // 1
      case .success:
        print("success")
        completion(nil)

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Congrats",
                              message: "Your payment was successful!",
                              preferredStyle: .alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
          self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
        alertController.addAction(alertAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
      // 2
      case .failure(let error):
        print("failure")
        completion(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also have a `StripeClient` set up as followed:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import Alamofire
import Stripe

enum Result {
  case success
  case failure(Error)
}

final class StripeClient {

  static let shared = StripeClient()

  private init() {
    // private
  }

  private lazy var baseURL: URL = {
    guard let url = URL(string: Constants.baseURLString) else {
      fatalError("Invalid URL")
    }
    return url
  }()
  func completeCharge(with token: STPToken, amount: Int, completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
    // 1
    let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("charge")
    // 2
    let params: [String: Any] = [
      "token": token.tokenId,
      "amount": amount,
      "currency": Constants.defaultCurrency,
      "description": Constants.defaultDescription
    ]
    // 3
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
      .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
      .responseString { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
          completion(Result.success)
        case .failure(let error):
          completion(Result.failure(error))
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added logging to determine how far execution gets? For example, does the `didCreateToken` delegate get called? Is the request to your backend server happening? What happens on your server, does it successfully process the request? Does the app see the response in the Alamofire callback?

Comment: @karllekko I have print statements throughout the above code, and the only statement that gets called is the `print("0")` that gets called in the `addCardViewControllerDidCancel`.